# Does the green color represents existence of Copper in it

Tags: color, chemical-biology

World is full of green, because of plants. Does it really signifies existence of Copper, in particularly by `leafs`.

I well understood that Prolific Tamarind Colored Salt has base element Copper. More usage of Tamarind makes us dump as per Siddhas in India.

Would like to know specifically that green color means existence of Copper. Is that completely true. Or by Alkali elements it might be faulty in some situation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll

Comment: Azurite is a copper mineral and it is blue. Metallic copper is reddish. Cuprite is a copper mineral and it is red. So there are a lot of copper minerals that are not green.

Comment: No, there are plenty of compounds, even metal complexes, which are green without containing copper

Comment: Die or pigment gets color by right agent which is been in use. Synthesizer gets [or] reveals color by/on physical principles which is not bounds to Chemical Bond, maybe its just a relevant to it.

Answer (score 4):

The green in plants arises not from copper but from chlorophyll.  It is true that many oxidized species of copper are green, but in plants, it is clorophyl as described for example in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll):

> "Chlorophyll (also chlorophyl) is any of several closely related green
>   pigments found in cyanobacteria and the chloroplasts of algae and
>   plants. Its name is derived from the Greek words χλωρός, chloros
>   ("green") and φύλλον, phyllon ("leaf"). Chlorophyll is essential in
>   photosynthesis, allowing plants to absorb energy from light.
>   Chlorophyll absorbs light most strongly in the blue portion of the
>   electromagnetic spectrum, followed by the red portion. Conversely, it
>   is a poor absorber of green and near-green portions of the spectrum,
>   which it reflects, producing the green color of chlorophyll-containing
>   tissues."

Comment: Does green pigment is green because of Copper?

Comment: No, there is actually no copper in chlorophyll, or enough copper in plants to produce the strong green we see.  Chlorophyll is purely organic, with a Mg bound to it.

Comment: Oh! ok! By mutation or by laws is there intervention that color formation gets using Copper, because it is pigment.

Comment: `Mg` I agree. But not every green is by `Mg`, if I am right.

Comment: That is correct.  To answer your question, copper plays absolutely no role whatsoever in the "green-ness" of plants.  Nice guess with your knowledge that forms of copper can be green, but as you know plenty other things are green, like the copper-free chlorophyll ;)

Comment: Thanks for Agreeing! When it is Organic `Mutation` plays important role than in `In-Organic`. So while, other elements can be placed as part of mutation in it, however it is so pure. And as per `Material Science` nothing is pure so.

Comment: Great!  I'm not sure whether I fully answered your question, but if you feel I was helpful please consider accepting the answer (or another one if a better one comes along).

Comment: Note that liquid chlorine is also green*ish*, hence *chlor*ine.

Comment: @WYSIWYG, I don't want it on my veggies, but good point ;)

Comment: @airhuff  *"Oh! ok! By mutation or by laws is there intervention that color formation gets using Copper, because it is pigment."* You actually understood this?! I applaud you ;p (+1's answer)

Comment: @paracresol, no that one was lost on me.  My "that is correct" comment referred to the immediately previous statement "But not every green is by Mg, if I am right"...I agree that not all green is caused by Mg ;)